# How to define a complicated function inside the body of Compile?

Tags: function-construction, compile

I want to compile a function in a way to keep its memory footprint down.  In the example below, I am trying to compile a function `f` that makes three calls to `bigNastyFunction`.  I do not want to define `bigNastyFunction` outside and use option `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True` because then three copies of that function will be inserted into the body of the compiled function verbatim, leading to excessive memory usage.  Instead, my strategy is to define `bigNastyFunction` inside a `Module` which is inside `Compile`.  My hope is that `bigNastyFunction` will be appropriately stored as a subroutine, and called by the body as needed.

```
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True];

f = Compile[{{x, _Complex}},
  Module[{bigNastyFunction = Function[{y}, Sin[y]]},

   bigNastyFunction[x] + bigNastyFunction[x^2]^2 + 3 bigNastyFunction[x^3]

 ]
]
```

The example above doesn't work because `Function` is not one of the functions that can be compiled by `Compile`.  What workaround is there to define a large (complicated) function *inside* the body of a `Compile`'d function?

Answer (score 6):

I think you need `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False`:

```
f = With[{bigNastyFunction = 
    Compile[{{y, _Complex}}, Sin[y](*,CompilationTarget\[Rule]C*)]}, 
  Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, 
   bigNastyFunction[x] + bigNastyFunction[x^2]^2 + 3 bigNastyFunction[x^3], 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False}]]
```

> ```
> ……
> 1 C1 = CompiledFunctionCall[ Hold[CompiledFunction[{y}, Sin[y], -CompiledCode-]][ C0]]
> 2 C2 = Square[ C0]
> ……
> ```

Related post:

[Is the CompiledFunctionCall WVM opcode efficient?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31273/1871)

[CompiledFunctionCall vs. LibraryFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82995/1871)

Comment: I think this takes more memory and time than just injecting the code (according to `ByteCount` and `RepeatedTiming`).

Comment: @MichaelE2  I guess it… depends on how the big nasty function is defined :D

Comment: +1 to your answer and your links, I learned some things today.

Comment: If you define `bigNastyFunction = Function[{y}, Sin[y]]` instead of using `Compile`, then `ByteCount[f]` goes down from 11704 to 4560, the same as @MichaelE2 's first answer.

Comment: Your method is always produces functions with about twice as big a `ByteCount` as mine (more than that when `bigNastyFunction` is small) because three copies of the compiled function are stored in `f`.  For expressions with a `LeafCount` up to about 500, your method is up to 20% slower than mine; from 500 or so up to 100,000, they're about the same speed; and at a `LeafCount` of 180,000, yours was about 10% faster.  (The expressions were random plus/times combinations of elementary functions.)

Comment: @xzczd Were you referring to Joel Klein? It didn't make sense to me until I read his answer just now. --- BTW, if both are compiled to C, yours is always a little faster. I'm not sure why: Calling subroutines vs. inlined code should introduce extra, if negligible, overhead; perhaps the optimization is different. (Yours is still bigger. I don't think the size is that important, but you seemed to bring it up initially.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, actually the memory cost is the only thing in my mind, because I think that's what OP is concerned. However, after checking `FullForm@f`, I noticed my answer is incorrect, it also inserts 3 copies of the (compiled) function into the body! So far I can't think out a way to define a sub routine as OP desires…

Comment: xzczd and @MichaelE2 thanks for trying.  I'm beginning to think that this is an unfortunate limitation of `Compile`.  I'll contact Wolfram Research about it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way:

```
With[{opts = SystemOptions[]},
 With[{bigNastyFunction = Function[{y}, Sin[y]]}, 
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "CompileReportExternal" -> True],
   f = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, 
     bigNastyFunction[x] + bigNastyFunction[x^2]^2 + 3 bigNastyFunction[x^3]],
   SetSystemOptions[opts]
   ]]]
```

Here's another way:

```
Module[{bigNastyFunction = Function[{y}, Sin[y]]},
 Block[{x},
  f = Compile @@ {{{x, _Complex}}, 
     bigNastyFunction[x] + bigNastyFunction[x^2]^2 + 3 bigNastyFunction[x^3]}
  ]]
```

To check:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]; 
CompilePrint@f
```

Comment: I think this has little difference with _define bigNastyFunction outside and use option `"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`_, because _then three copies of that function will be inserted into the body of the compiled function verbatim"_

Comment: @xzczd Depends on how the big nasty function is defined....

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no solution like c language. A workaround is based on list.

```
    bigNastyFunction =Compile[{{y, _Complex}}, Sin[y](*,CompilationTarget\[Rule]C*)]
    f = Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, 
    Block[{xl = {x, x^2, x^3}, coefList = {1, 1, 3},fx}, fx = 
    Table[bigNastyFunction[ii], {ii, xl}];fx[[2]] = fx[[2]]^2;
    fx.coefList], CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
    "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False}];
```

The compiled code by CompilePrint[f] is

```
    1 argument
    8 Integer registers
    5 Complex registers
    4 Tensor registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking on
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    C0 = A1
    I3 = 0
    I7 = 4
    I6 = 2
    T(I1)1 = {1, 1, 3}
    I2 = 1
    I0 = 3
    Result = C1

    1   C3 = Square[ C0]
    2   C1 = Power[ C0, I0]
    3   T(C1)2 = {C0, C3, C1}
    4   I5 = Length[ T(C1)2]
    5   I4 = I3
    6   T(C1)0 = Table[ I5]
    7   I1 = I3
    8   goto 12
    9   C3 = GetElement[ T(C1)2, I1]
    10  C4 = CompiledFunctionCall[ Hold[CompiledFunction[{y}, Sin[y],-CompiledCode-]] 
    [[C3]]
    11  Element[ T(C1)0, I4] = C4
    12  if[ ++ I1 <= I5] goto 9
    13  C1 = Part[ T(C1)0, I6]
    14  C4 = Square[ C1]
    15  Part[ T(C1)0, I6] = C4
    16  T(C1)3 = CoerceTensor[ I7, T(I1)1]]
    17  C1 = DotVV[ T(C1)0, T(C1)3, I7]]
    18  Return
```