# Compile with function definition inside

Tags: compile

How can I compile a code with target C containing function definition inside?

I saw post using `With`. But this just inserts the function in the appropriate place like macros in C.
[Suggestion with `With`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105815/how-to-define-a-complicated-function-inside-the-body-of-compile)

```
    f = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
      g[y] = y^2;

      g[x]
      , CompilationTarget -> "C"
      ]
```

Calls `Main`:

```
In[12]:= CompilePrint[f]


1 argument
        3 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        Result = R2

1   V17 = MainEvaluate[                       2
Function[{x}, g[y] = y ][ R0]]
2   R2 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[g][ R0]]
3   Return
```

Comment: Why can't you just define `g` as a separate function instead of making the definition within `Compile[]`?

Comment: @J.M. I trying to minimize all overheads of calling various pieces, by putting everything in a big compiled function.

Comment: Can't do it without using tricks to preprocess (rewrite) the input. Just define it externally, either as a compiled definition or otherwise, and set appropriate options to inline it into the parent function.

Comment: @OleksandrR. will the inlining mean the the body of the compiled function will call `MainEvaluate` ?

Comment: If the function can be inlined, it will be compiled as fully as it would be if it were specified directly as part of the outer function body.

Comment: Other tricks/tactics include injecting the definition and evaluating it inside; `cfunc = With[{gg = g}, Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Evaluate[gg[x]]]];`.This falls into the macro category as noted above. I think it was the main way to do this sort of thing prior to the introduction of `InlineExternalDefinitions`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First define the function normally:

```
g[y_] := y^2;
```

Then substitute the definition in:

```
f = ReleaseHold[Hold[Compile[{{x, _Real}},
 g[x], CompilationTarget -> "C"]] /. DownValues[g]]
```

And there is no longer `MainEvaluate`in the compiled function.

As Oleksandr R.  suggested, you can also do

```
g = #^2 &;
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}},
  g[x], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

Comment: A good workaround; +1. It is essentially the same as the `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` option accomplishes, but rather more transparent in how it works.

Comment: @Oleksandr R.: It's not only more transparent as it seems, but also more powerful. Think of a compiled function that contains a `Sum`, i.e. the body of the function is sth like `x = Range[n]; Sum[v[x], {i, 1, n}]` where `n` is an integer argument to that function. Now, `v[x]` is defined outside of the compiled environment as `v[x_] := Part[x, i]`. This now compiles through even without even specifying `i` as a second argument to `v`. On the other hand, I haven't been able to define sth like `v=Part[#1,#2]&;` outside of the compiled function and inline it without calls to `MainEvaluate`.

Answer (score 8):

Your question probably will not get the answer you are looking for, because although it is technically possible, getting `Compile` to work properly is hard enough already without the added difficulty of automatically preprocessing its input. Thus I think that this approach will tend to obscure and complicate the job, rather than making anything easier.

The simple answer is: it's not possible because the VM doesn't have any concept of a "function type". The only allowable types are numeric quantities or void. So, you can write

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Function[{y}, y^2][x]]
```

and it compiles and operates just as it should. But you can't have

```
Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Module[{g}, g = Function[{y}, y^2]; g[x]]]
```

because `g` is not something that can be represented inside the VM. The code of the function can be, but the treatment of that code as a named quantity is an abstraction too far.