# Use iterator outside of iteration

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I want to `Map` something that is depending on an iterator from the outside of e.g. `Table` into the procedure.

What would be the correct way to do this in *Mathematica* without evoking error messages.

Here is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

```
list = {a, b, c};
Map[
  Table[#, {i, Length[list]}] &, 
  { list[[i]] }
]
```

**[Edit]**

Since my initial post was a little bit unclear to what I really intend to do, I want to provide another, hopefully clearer example. I am currently experimenting a lot with MMA's `Compile` function and wondered how one could define a function outside of a compiled function that will be called within the body of the compiled function and may depend on an iteration variable that is counted withing the `Compile` enviroment. I then stumbled over this thread [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118775/compile-with-function-definition-inside) which was helpful.

A minimum working example of what I intend to do would be

```
v[x_] := Part[x, i];

cf = Hold@
     Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
      Block[{v, x}, x = Range[n]; Sum[v[x], {i, 1, n}]], 
      CompilationTarget :> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] //. 
    DownValues@v // ReleaseHold;

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
Grid[{{CompilePrint[cf]}}, Frame -> All]
```

where now the compiled functions compiles through without any calls to `MainEvaluate`.

On the other hand, as is stated in the linked thread one can typically inline pure external functions into a compiled function by using the option `"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True`. However, in this case this strategy doesn't seem to be successful. Something like

```
v = Part[#1, #2] &;

cf2 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{v, x}, x = Range[n]; Sum[v[x, i], {i, 1, n}]], 
   CompilationTarget :> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
Grid[{{CompilePrint[cf2]}}, Frame -> All]
```

won't compile through without calls to `MainEvaluate` while something like

```
g = #^2 &;
cf3 = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, g[x], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

does compile through.

Of course, one can still wonder why I wouldn't inject the definition of `v[x]` directly into the compiled function. But for my purposes it is more convenient to have one compiled function and change the function `v[x]` outside of the compiled function where I can now use different function definitions of `v[x]` for the same compiled function.

Comment: Given `list = {a, b, c}`, what outcome would you expect?

Comment: `{{a,b,c}}` in this case, but I want to avoid the error message `Part::pspec: Part specification i is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>`. Tried to use `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` but maybe I misplaced it. The `list[[i]]` shouldn't be evaluated before it is stuffed into the `Table`.

Comment: The question is more conceptual based, it is not a question of how to get the same answer in a different way.

Comment: Then why is `{list}` not acceptable?

Comment: Because the actual elements depend on the iteration process and cannot be specified a priori.

Comment: I am sorry but this does not make sense to me. What do you want to `Map`? Don't you need a nested `Table` or `MapIndexed` instead ?

Comment: What about `{Table[list[[i]], {i, Length[list]}]}` - does it work for you?

Comment: Please see my [Edit] to the OP and I apologise thoroughly for the confusion I have caused.

Comment: The power of `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` option is just limted, at least up to now. That's why I prefer `With` and `/.` for inlining. BTW the most unreasonable failure I've found: `n = 5;
test = Compile[{}, Do[i, {i, n}], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]; CompilePrint[test]`.

Comment: Yeah, since it can be so cumbersome I think I will check out plain C over Christmas even though I like MMA. @xzczd: Yeah need to localise the `n` variable then it is alright. This is what I learned about `Compile`, no matter what you do always localise your variables.

Comment: The issue in my example is not localization, the issue is, `n` should be inlined by `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` in principle. Check the following example: `n = 5; test2 = 
 Compile[{}, Do[i + n, {i, 8}], 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]; CompilePrint[test2]`

Comment: Ok, now I got your point. Nevertheless, localisation resolves the first case  for some reason and doesn't harm the second one, though the behaviour in the first case is weird then I agree. `"InlineExternalDefinitions"` is then certainly not behaving as it is supposed to according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe use `Unevaluated` or pass a function:

```
Map[Table[#, {i, Length[list]}] &, {Unevaluated[list[[i]]]}]
Map[Table[#[i], {i, Length[list]}] &, {list[[#]] &}]
```

Comment: Yes I think that comes close to what I need. Thank you!