# How to define a function inside a Compile?

Tags: equation-solving, compile

I want to compile a variety of commands, including a function. I need to map this function, inside the compilation, and I can't include the function without facing errors such as "*CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 27; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation.*"

The code finds the root of a function, it's a complicated way to do it but as I want to compute roots of complicated functions I can't simply use *FindRoot*.

For simplicity I'll include an example in which I try to evaluate the root of $y^3+5y^2−5$, such as 0.919089. Note that the problem is in the line "*gg[y_] = y^3 + 5 y^2 - 5;*"

```
Raiz = Compile[{{xmin, _Real}, {xmax, _Real}, {npts, _Real}},
  Module[{xrange, tab, par, roots, pos, xtab, xt, xmin2, xmax2, xmed},
    xrange = With[{d1 = N@xmin, d2 = N@xmax},
      d1+(d2-d1)/(npts-1) Range[0,npts-1]];
  gg[y_] = y^3 + 5 y^2 - 5;
  tab = Map[gg, xrange];
  par = Partition[tab, 2, 1];
  roots = Flatten@Select[par, NonPositive[Times @@ #] &];
  pos = Flatten[Position[tab, #] & /@ roots];
  xtab = Partition[xrange[[pos]], 2];
  Table[
    xmin2 = xt[[1]]; xmax2 = xt[[2]];
      Do[
        xmed = N@(xmax2 + xmin2)/2;
        If[Sign[gg[xmin2] gg[xmed]] == 1, xmin2 = xmed, xmax2 = xmed];
      ,npts];
    (xmin2 + xmax2)/2
  , {xt, xtab}]
 ]
]
```

Sorry if it's a duplicate, I couldn't find any answer for my problem.

Comment: Could be helpful https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24595/66

Answer (score 14):

This is covered by the 3rd rule in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104031/1871):

> Compiled evaluation can't work with patterns… Notice that function
>   definition like `f[x_] = …` or `f[x_] := …` also uses pattern so they
>   can't be compiled.

So, how to circumvent? There exist at least 2 types of possible approaches.

1. As mentioned by [halirutan](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/187/halirutan), define the function `gg` as another compiled function **outside** and then introduce it with **`With`** or  **`"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True`**.

   Notice the `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True` option isn't actually necessary to make the code fully compiled. `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False` will just lead to a `CompiledFunctionCall`, which [isn't slow](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31273/1871). Of course, sometimes inlining the compiled function manually speeds up the code, but not always, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105815/how-to-define-a-complicated-function-inside-the-body-of-compile/105833#comment287588_105833) for an example.

   Instead of compiled function, one can also define `gg` as a pure function (`Function`), see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24597/1871) for an example.
2. Meta-programming based on pattern-matching:

   ```
   gg[y_] = y^3 + 5 y^2 - 5;
   cf = ReleaseHold[Hold@Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}}, Map[gg[#]&, list]] /. DownValues@gg]
   ```

   Notice I've rewrite `Map[gg, …]` to `Map[gg[#]&,…`, or `Downvalues@gg` won't match it. As to the advantage of this approach, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47485/1871) for one example.

Answer (score 9):

That is a weak point of *Mathematica*. We have questions here that explain how to include other compiled functions into a compiled function. For your specific case you could use something along this line:

```
gg = Compile[{{y, _Real, 0}},
   y^3 + 5 y^2 - 5
   ];

With[{gg = gg},
 fc = Compile[{{list, _Real, 1}},
   Map[gg, list],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
   ]
 ]
```

This creates a real inlined function and you should be aware of this. The body of the function `gg`, meaning the `y^3 + 5 y^2 - 5` par, is copied at each place you are calling `gg` inside `fc`.

For small functions `gg`, the option `"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True` is not necessary. For larger functions `gg`, if you don't set this option, you will get a `CompiledFunctionCall` inside `fc`.

The crucial part of understanding is, that inlining a function means that your final `fc` might become very large because it will contain a copy of `gg` at every place where you call it. Be aware of that.